# Why am I getting the error "Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end" when downloading a file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, download

I am trying to download the files stored in azure blob storage using the url to the individual blobs.

I am downloading five blob files and i do have the separate urls to all those blob files.

Below is my code:

```
function Download()
{
  const fs = require('fs');
  const path = require('path');
  const https = require('https');
  const url = require('url');

  var sasToken = '?sv=2019-02-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2019-10-3xxxxxxxZ&sp=rl'
  var blobUris = ['https:xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx'];

  var i;
  for(i=0; i<blobUris.length; i++)
  {
    var sasUrl = blobUris[i] + sasToken;
    var filename=url.parse(blobUris[i]).pathname.split('/').pop();
    var filePath = "D:/BLESensor"
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(filePath+"/"+filename)
    var request = https.get(sasUrl, function(response) {
      response.pipe(file);
        //  Promise.resolve()
        //  .then(() => file.destroy())
        //  .catch(console.log)
  });
}

  }
return Download();
```

I am getting the below error when i run the function:

```
Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:248:12)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:296:5)
    at IncomingMessage.ondata (_stream_readable.js:709:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:504:10)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:973:34)
    at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:954:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at errorOrDestroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:107:12)
    at WriteStream.onerror (_stream_readable.js:733:7)
    at WriteStream.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at errorOrDestroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:107:12)
    at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:250:3)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:296:5)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:973:34)
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There's not enough information here but I suspect that you will solve your problem as you learn the fundamentals of asynchrounous programming 
in JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to the fact that we're downloading in a for loop while the https.get call (like all Node.js I/O calls) is asynchronous. So response.pipe is not going to work correctly in this case (since the file stream will be closed by the time response.pipe is called) with a function scoped file variable (e.g. var file..)

There is simple fix for this issue, we just need to ensure that the file variable is [block scoped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), e.g. use either [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) or [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) for this.

```
function Download()
{
  const fs = require('fs');
  const path = require('path');
  const https = require('https');
  const url = require('url');

  var sasToken = '?sv=2019-02-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2019-10-3xxxxxxxZ&sp=rl'
  var blobUris = ['https:xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx'];

  var i;
  for(i=0; i<blobUris.length; i++)
  {
    var sasUrl = blobUris[i] + sasToken;
    var filename=url.parse(blobUris[i]).pathname.split('/').pop();
    var filePath = "D:/BLESensor"
    // Make sure file variable is block scoped. We could use const too.. but not var!
    let file = fs.createWriteStream(filePath+"/"+filename)
    console.log("Downloading file: " + (i+1));
    var request = https.get(sasUrl, function(response) {
        response.pipe(file);
    });
  }

}

return Download();
```